# input.less NOT Overwriting style.css in WordPress Theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, less

Currently I'm developing a WordPress Theme, but in theme panel, if user want to change the css for ex: body background color, the color is not changing in theme as well as in frontend. For changing of all css properties, I used less css file named input.less in which I had one css property of "background-color: #fff;" and in input.less I used a variable "background-color: @body_bg_color;" and I defined this variable "@body_bg_color;" in variables.php file. But somehow, it's not working. What should I do?

Here is my content in theme's stylesheet style.css :

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

and my content in input.less file:

```
body{
    background: @body_bg_color; 
}
```

and variable @body_bg_color defined in variabls.php file

```
$less->setVariables(array(
    "body_bg_color"  => $body_bg_color,
));
```

Comment: How are you compiling your less? Using the less app? less.js? Perhaps your less build isn't working.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Thank you for your response. I'm compiling my less using less.js

Comment: Some more thoughts here: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/less-js-and-wordpress/. I normally use the local LESS app (I'm on a mac) and compile a separate custom.less that renders to custom.css that I then import to the style.css file to keep WordPress's comments in that file so the theme works.